# UPDATE и $_SERVER не стыкуются

Tags: php, mysql, update

Есть небольшой сайт, при регистрации на котором генерируется QR-код. В QR-коде зашита ссылка на страницу, на которой человек может оценить "зарегистрированного". Ссылка выглядит вот так:

```
mark.php?mail=$email
```

На странице `mark.php` производится разбор адресной строки. Из нее выдергивается `email`, передается в функцию и затем используется в запросе `UPDATE`. Изначально ссылка выглядела так

```
mark.php?$email
```

а страница так:

```
<form method = "get" id = "mark">
    <table border = "0" class = "radios">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "mark" value = "1"></td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "mark" value = "2"></td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "mark" value = "3"></td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "mark" value = "4"></td>
            <td><input type = "radio" name = "mark" value = "5"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Оценить">
</form>



include ("connect.php"); //подключение к базе
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firms WHERE email='$mail'", $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$users = $row['email'];
if (isset($_GET['mark'])){
    $mark = $_GET['mark'];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$users'");
 }
```

При простом выводе `echo $users` мы получаем `email`. Но `UPDATE` забивает на это и ничего в столбец `mark` не пишет. Только если явно объявлять `email` или в `UPDATE`, или в другой переменной. Потом я попробовал использовать `parse_url`, ссылка приобрела вид

```
mark.php?mail=$email
```

и код

```
include ("connect.php");
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$part = parse_url($user);
parse_str($part[query]);
$need = $mail;
if (isset($_GET['mark'])){
    $mark = $_GET['mark'];
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$need'");
}
```

На всякий случай даже сделал `$need`, и все равно `UPDATE` показал болт. Потом решил, что все дело в изменяющейся адресной строке после нажатия кнопки, сделал константу и снова - болт. Даже все в `UPDATE` писалось в формате `'" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . "'`. Изменение кодировки как в коде, так и базе, результата не дало. Жесткое задание переменной в string - тоже самое. Вариант с

```
echo "UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$mail'";
```

ничего не отображает. Даже такой вариант - 0 результата! В комментариях приведено то, что выводится:

```
include ("connect.php");
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $user."<br>";
$part = parse_url($user);
parse_str($part[query]);
$mail = (string)$mail;
echo $mail."<br>"; //выводит email

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM firms WHERE email='$mail'", $db);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$users = $row['email'];
    echo $users; //также выводит

if (isset($_GET['mark'])){
    $mark = $_GET['mark'];
    //$query = mysql_query("UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$mail'");
    echo "UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$mail'"."<br>"; //UPDATE firms SET mark = '5' WHERE email = ''
            echo "UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$users'"; //UPDATE firms SET mark = '5' WHERE email = ''
}
```

Друзья, есть ли у кого идеи, как быть? Может копаю не туда? Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: А что по вашему у вас $_GET["mark"]? По вашему описанию он абсолютно пустой.

Comment: @Ruslan, он не пустой, если записать UPDATE без WHERE, в базу запишется оценка, но во все строки.

Comment: а откуда там берется значение? Вы сами его инициализируете? Потому как в приведенной ссылки нет переменной mark, а $_GET это именно массив данных берущий свой параметры из ссылки.

Comment: Либо там mark все таки есть, но тогда попытка взять email через REQUEST_URI должен возвращать строку с mark=xxx, но вы говорите, что там только email. Что-то у меня ваши слова не сходятся с тем, что я вижу. Поправьте мою ошибку.

Comment: @Ruslan, $_GET['mark'] получает данные из формы по имени - оценку. Если вывести $mark, то мы увидим выбранное число. При этом в базу ничего не занесется, если только напрямую в WHERE не записать нужный email или также в любую переменную записать email как строку, а потом указать на WHERE. $_GET работает, куда-то теряются данные из $mark и $users.

Comment: Чудеса прямо =) А для чего такие извращения? Вы ведь уже сделали parse_str и переменная $mark в этот момент уже объявлена в этой области видимости? Тоже самое в обратном смысле по email, который уже присутствует в $_GET тамже где mark. Что пишет `var_dump($_GET)`?

Comment: @Ruslan, вы не путаете mail и mark?

Comment: array(2) { ["mark"]=> string(1) "5" ["submit"]=> string(14) "Оценить" } - вот, что пишет var_dump($_GET). Все работает.

Comment: Простите, перепутал) $mail и $users, конечно)

Comment: судя по var_dump($_GET) всё вполне ожидаемо. email отсутствует в массиве данных поступивших из формы. Я не знаю откуда у вас данные, что он там есть. Но var_dump говорит четко - email отсутствует, и соответственно он отсутствует в вашем запросе на update.

Answer (score 1):

Решение. Данные пропадали из-за того, что переменная динамически менялась каждый раз после отправки формы. $_GET срабатывает и переписывает данные. parse_url и все остальное не срабатывали именно по этому. Таковы особенности PHP-переменных. 
Что можно сделать? Поменять $_GET на $_POST и сделать запись в файл. В первом файл - mark.php - меняем код на такой:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$part = parse_url($user);
parse_str($part[query]);
$users = $mail;
$file = 'email.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current = $users;
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Соответственно в форме меняет method на post (method = "post"), action = "send.php". В send.php прописываем следующее:

```
include ("connect.php");
if (isset($_POST['mark'])){
        $mark = $_POST['mark'];
        $file = 'email.txt';
        $get = file_get_contents($file);
        $query = mysql_query("UPDATE firms SET mark = '$mark' WHERE email = '$get'");
        echo "FINALLY!"."<br>";
}
else echo "OOOPS!";
```

echo можно сделать любыми. Так все будет работать.